# Can't add entire project to git

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I am trying to backup my project, however only some files are being backed up.
[image]

And when I try and right click on the project to add the rest of the files the option to add GIT isn't available.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check where your .git folder is located. Maybe the .git folder is not in the root path of your project. If that is the case try to remove the .git folder and do a git init in your project root folder.

OBS. Removing the .git folder will remove everything to do with version control for that project.